# wanted to adapt this tradingview strategy, but having problems again

Tags: algorithmic-trading, indicator, pine-script

I found this simple strategy which I thought I understood, and tried to adapt by adding one simple "if" logic to it, and I broke it.

```
//@version=4
strategy("Kozlod - RSI Strategy - 1 minute", overlay=true, 
 default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, commission_value=0.0025, default_qty_value=100)

// 
// author: Kozlod
// date: 2019-05-12
// https://www.tradingview.com/u/Kozlod/
// https://t.me/quantnomad
//

// Inputs
length = input(65)
overSold = input(40)
overBought = input(60)
price = input(close)

// RSI
vrsi = rsi(price, length)

boughtp = if crossover(vrsi, overSold)
    strategy.entry("RsiLE", strategy.long, comment="RsiLE")
    close

if crossunder(vrsi, overBought) and close >= boughtp*0.0025 +boughtp
    strategy.entry("RsiSE", strategy.short, comment="RsiSE")
```

The original code was

```
vrsi = rsi(price, length)

if crossover(vrsi, overSold)
    strategy.entry("RsiLE", strategy.long, comment="RsiLE")

if crossunder(vrsi, overBought)
    strategy.entry("RsiSE", strategy.short, comment="RsiSE")
```

What I attempted to do was to coax the algorithm to only sell if the price after the initial buy was greater than a certain percentage + the bought price.

That way I can take the exchange fees into account in figuring out if a strategy is wroth it.

And if it's not worth it, there is no point in making the buy and sell. it should just wait until the price is such that the buy and sell yields a profit.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your previous code wasn't saving the bought price across bars and always reinitialized it with the `=` operator. This code saves it properly and plots your test value so you can see it. I've added a condition on position size to only save a new bought value when the long entry is executed, otherwise your `boughtp` variable would be assigned a new value every time a cross occurs, which doesn't always translate into a new order.

```
var boughtp = 0.0
if crossover(vrsi, overSold) and strategy.position_size <= 0
    strategy.entry("RsiLE", strategy.long, comment="RsiLE")
    boughtp := close

plot(boughtp * 1.0025, style = plot.style_circles)
```

Comment: This behaves completely different from the original kozlod code. https://imgur.com/CxC0nQI That shows that the trade has been executed based on the rule, and it so happens to be above the limit I have. (it made 0.9% profit) Now if i run your code, https://imgur.com/4c3b1Aj i get nothing in that window because no buy/sell has been executed, but clearly the trade opportunity in the middle should have been picked up by tradingview? (this might be due to the position size, which I'm having problems understanding?)

Comment: If you want your strategy to behave like the original code, just use the original code.

Comment: That's really missing the point. The point was that the code is not picking up the obvious trade it should have picked up on since the profit was way above what I have specified as the bound.  Yes, I can use the original code, but that doesn't help me in understanding how to do this stuff. My initial point stands. How do we set up a strategy so that it will meet more than one condition when it included price increase requirement?